# php curl not returning bash result

Tags: command-line, bash, php, curl

I have a file on the remote server called test.sh which returns two lines when called from the command line with './test.sh'.

So far so good.

I also have a php file with a curl command called result.php on my shared server:

```
$target_url = $url_ip."/get-num-images-by-date.sh";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,  TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

The file on the remote server has all the correct permissions (755) and ownership (www-data).

However, var_dump($response); does not return the two lines of code. Instead, it returns the content of the test.sh file:

```
string(182) "#!/bin/bash #sudo find /mnt/usbstick/images -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td\n' | sort | uniq -c sudo find /mnt/usbstick/images -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td\n' | sort | uniq -c exit; "
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is get-num-images-by-date.sh the same as test.sh? And is your remote server different from the shared server? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, test.sh and get-num-images-by-date.sh are the same. Sorry about the confusion. The remote server is actually a raspberry pi and different from my shared server with a hosting company.

Comment: I think the problem is to do with '-printf' in the find command...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why you're seeing the script itself

The problem is the following: `curl` performs a web request for the remote server to serve you the file at a given URL (e.g. `http:///example.com/get-num-images-by-date.sh`). The web server running on `example.com` now has to decide what to do when a request for such a file arrives. By default, a web server will just render the file contents.

Web servers with the correct configuration will know what to do with `.php` files, for example. They'll run the PHP code in the file through a PHP interpreter, and only render what the PHP code outputs. This is what most users want when installing a “LAMP stack” (Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP), and I assume that your web server on the remote server will render PHP files by default.

For your shell script, the web server has obviously not executed the file in Bash, but instead just printed its content — that's what you're seeing as the `curl` result. This is, actually, a good thing! If web servers executed all executable scripts by default, that'd be quite concerning in terms of security.

#### What you can do

There are two options for you:

1. Enable CGI processing for your server (e.g. [for Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html)) and let it run shell scripts.
2. Create a PHP script at `http:///example.com/get-num-images-by-date.php` that calls the Bash script via the `shell_exec()` function and prints its output.

The second option would be much more common these days.

#### A note on security

Look at your shell script: it contains a `sudo` call. If you want to be able to run the script from a simple URL call, the web server user would have to have root privileges on your machine, which means that an attacker could theoretically gain access to the complete Linux installation.

It is therefore recommended to only give your web server user (`apache` or `httpd`) access to a limited set of directories/files that it is supposed to access. You should then look at rewriting your shell script so it does not require `sudo`. One way of doing this would be to mount the external drive with read-only permissions for the web server user.

Comment: Thank you sooo much, for the very informative answer! Will create a php file tomorrow.